# Is there plotly option to use custom axes scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, scale

I would like to use a custom axes scale in Plotly (for use in Python) other than the linear and log scales available.

An example of this in matplotlib is here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/scales/custom_scale.html

Does plotly have something similar?

Comment: Doesn't appear to - https://plotly.com/python/axes/. That's unfortunate.